# Using Twig's replace filter with getURL()

Tags: https

I have a template that displays in both http and https environments. When pulling my images for the https environment I need to be able to change the URL to https:// from http://. I tried

```
{{ gist.gistImage.first().getUrl('gistUnit')|replace({'http': https}) }}
```

based on the documentation here twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html

Not working. Is this because getURL() gets processed after the filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
{{ gist.gistImage.first().getUrl('gistUnit')|replace({'http': 'https'}) }}
```

Comment: even better: `replace({'http://': 'https://'})` so you won't map `https://` to `httpss://`